# Plotting a fourier series in matlab with for loop

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to plot the fourier series following fourier series;

```
f(t)=$$\sum_{k=0}^k \frac{(1)(\sin(2k+1)pi*t)}{2k+1}$$
```

[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Nop.jpg)

for t = -1:0.0001:1

i tried using a for loop and incrementing the value of the new series by F + the last series and to also increase k by 1 each iteration, but the plot i got is a square instead of a sin wave

```
k=0
series  = 0
for i = 0:0.0001:1;
    F = 4/pi*((1/(2*(k) + 1)).*sin((2*(k)+1).*pi.*t));
    series = series + F;
    k = k+1;
end 
plot(t,series)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a mistake in what you are looping over, you actually don't want to loop over time, but over `k`. Right now you are looping over `i` (which represents time, from context), but you are not even using `i`.

So the correct way would be to loop `k`, and set a maximum number of Fourier coefficients to include, like so:

```
series  = 0;
t = -1:0.0001:1;
k_max = 10;

for k = 0:k_max
    F = 4/pi*((1/(2*(k) + 1)).*sin((2*(k)+1).*pi.*t));
    series = series + F;
end

plot(t,series)
```

You can compare what happens when you include more coefficients, by changing `k_max`:

[image]

---

In Matlab, it is however generally faster to avoid using `for` loops, which can be done by vectorization. If you specify `t` as a row vector, and a vector `k` as a column vector, you can compute `F` for every `k`, and then sum this along the first dimension to obtain the series:

```
t = -1:0.0001:1;
k = (0:10).';

F = 4/pi.*((1./(2.*(k) + 1)).*sin((2*(k)+1).*pi.*t));
series = sum(F, 1);
```